# How To Transform A Table Into A Navigational Bar With HTML

Tags: html, css, datatable, navigation

I recently created a table for my website. Using HTML, how could I click on one of the pieces of table data, so that it would re-direct me to another tab on the website. 
For HTML the coding for just the table looks like this:

```
<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Home</td>
    <td>Produce</td>
    <td>Contact, Location, and Hours</td>
    <td>Join The Fresh Fiesta!</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**For CSS, the table coding looks like this:**

```
<style>

    table{
       border: 8px solid #0080C0;
       border-right-width:8px solid #008c0;
       width:1090px;
       height:70px;
       background-color:#0080C0;
       text-align:center;
     } 

    td{
       width:1090px;
       height:40px;
       background-color:#4BA0BB;
       font-family:'Franklin Gothic Heavy'; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-
       decoration: none; font-size: 15pt; color: #008000;
       border-radius: 5px;
       margin:auto;
       text-align:center;
     }
  </style>
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me transform this table into a navigation bar.

Comment: Try it yourself and then come back with the part you are stuck with.

Comment: You may want to look into anchors like for example `<a href="/">Home</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Using table is not the good approach in html for designing,
 - Use 
    `<ul>
         <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
         <li<a href="#">Produce</a></li>
         <li<a href="#">Contact, Location, and Hours</a></li>
         <li<a href="#">Join The Fresh Fiesta!</a></li>
     </ul>`
Css

```
ul li
{
  display:inline;
}
active 
{
  background-color:#ff9900;
}
```

- If you are using Html5, then use **nav**
   [sample nav tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp)